# Colon and equals under product operator

Tags: functions

I'm trying to understand the following equation:

$\prod_{i:y_i=1} p(x_i) \prod_{i:y_i=0} (1 - p(x_i))$

The part I don't get is the subscript below the product operator. Does the $i:y_i=1$ under the product operator mean "for every i where $y_i = 1$"?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly. By $\prod_{i: P(i)} t_i$, one means the product of those terms $t_i$ where $P(i)$ is true.